# What type of esata cable should I buy to connect to this port on my MB?

Tags: motherboard, sata

My motherboard AX370-Gaming K5-CF has 2 Sata Express ports as depicted in the manual in page 17 between the normal sata ports.

http://download.gigabyte.eu/FileList/Manual/mb_manualga-ax370-gaming-k5_e.pdf

On top of the ports it says "Lotes"

I was wondering what cable fits in there. I bought a standard esata cable online but it's double the size this port has. The cable I bought is this one  but it's double the width. Like a normal sata cable whilst the port is half the size

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The small one is *not* the SATA Express connector. Each SATA Express connector consists of two ordinary SATA connectors *and* the small one, all in line.

Here, you see two SATA Express connector on the motherboard: a used one and a free one:

[image]

Similarly, here's a SATA Express cable:

[image]

You may also be interested by [What Is SATA Express?](https://www.anandtech.com/show/7843/testing-sata-express-with-asus/2) article.

Comment: Ah I see, so my boards sata ports can be used as standalone sata ports or as part of a sata express connection. Thank you very much for clarifying